# Bash script to cd into newest directory within a directory

Tags: bash, directory-structure

I am trying to add a function to a data collection bash script I am writing. The intention would be to point to a specific directory, and then cd into the NEWEST directory within the parents.

Pseudocode:

```
cd top_dir
    for each dir in top_dir:
      age = dir.age
      if age < least_age:
        least_age = age
        newest_dir = dir

    cd newest_dir
```

I have tried using `cd "$( find "$1"/* -prune -type d 2>/dev/null | xargs stat -c "%Y %n" 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)"` from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/850576/cd-to-newest-directory), but that instead cd's me into the newest directory on my computer.

The intention would be for a directory structure like below:

```
parent_dir:
  child_1 | Last Edited 1 Hr Ago
  child_2 | Last Edited 1 Yr Ago
  child_3 | Last Edited 2 Yr Ago
  child_4 | Last Edited 1 Min Ago
  child_5 | Last Edited 1 Week Ago
```

The command would `cd` me into `child_4`

Comment: You aren't setting `$1` to `top_dir` first, probably because you aren't defining a function that has the attempted command as its body. The string `""/` is equivalent to `/`.

Comment: `bash` makes it incredibly difficult to do things like this. In `zsh`, for example, you would just write `cd top_dir/*(/om[1])`. (The parenthesized list after `*` is a set of glob qualifiers: `/` matches only directories, `om` sorts by modification date, and `[1]` returns only the first item of the resulting expansion.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you are trying to use is intended to be the body of a function; calling the function sets `$1` properly. By itself, `$1` probably isn't set, and so `find` operators on `""/` (same as `/`), not `top_dir`.

```
new_cd () {
  cd "$( find "$1"/* -prune -type d 2>/dev/null | xargs stat -c "%Y %n" 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-)"
}

new_cd top_dir
```

This can be simplified a little. There's no need to use `find` or `xargs`; a simple loop will do. And since you have a function now, there's no need to cram everything in one line.

```
new_cd () {
  new_d=$(for d in "$1"/*/; do
      stat -c "%Y %n" "$d" 2> /dev/null
  done | sort -nr |
         head -n |
         cut -d " " -f 2-)
  cd "$new_d"
}
```

This has one minor drawback: the command substitution will eat any trailing newlines in the output of `cut`, so make sure none of your directory names ends with a newline character. (This extremely minor bug can be fixed, but it probably isn't worth doing so; just be aware of it.)

It also has a bigger drawback: since *non*-trailing newlines *aren't* eaten, you cannot assume the output of the loop consists of exactly one file per line; a single file could occupy multiple lines. The easiest fix is to avoid directory names with newlines. A more robust fix abandons the pipeline.

```
new_cd () {
  local newest_time newest_d
  for d in "$1"/*/; do
    t=$(stat -c "%Y" "$d")
    if (( t > newest_time )); then
      newest_time=$t
      newest_d=$d
    fi
  done
  cd "$newest_d"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the most recent subdirectory using `ls -ldt */ | head -1` : the t option sorts files by date and */ matches only subdirectories, not files.

Comment: Only if that newest directory name contains no newlines, of course.