# Windows cmd cd into newest directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, cd

I have a deployment directory that contains subdirectories, one for each deployment. I'm trying to write a batch script that, among other things, performs a `cd` into the newest one of these directories.

I know how to do this in `bash` (has already been ansered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049463/7069126) as well), but I don't know how to accomplish the same thing in Windows `cmd`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a batch file following lines can be used to changed to the subdirectory with newest modification date:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir * /AD /B /O-D 2^>nul') do cd "%%I" & goto DoneCD
echo No subdirectory found in: "%CD%"
:DoneCD
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` starts a new command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified between `'` as further arguments in background. So executed by **FOR** is with usual Windows installation path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir * /AD /B /O-D 2>nul
```

**DIR** executed by background command process searches with the specified arguments

- in current directory
- for directories because of option `/AD` (attribute directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*` (all)

and outputs

- in bare format because of option `/B` just the directory names without path never enclosed in `"`
- ordered reverse by last modification date because of option `/O-D` and not using option `/TC` (creation date) or `/TA` (last access date) which means first the newest modified directory and last the oldest modified directory.

The output by **DIR** is written to handle **STDOUT** of the started background command process.

`2>nul` redirects the error message output by **DIR** on not finding any directory in current directory from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress this error message.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything written by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores empty lines which do not occur here because of **DIR** outputs the list of directory names without empty lines because of using `/B`.

**FOR** would split up by default a line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab character as delimiters. After this substring splitting is done **FOR** would by default check if the first substring starts with default end of line character `;` in which case the line would be ignored like an empty line. Otherwise **FOR** would assign first space/tab delimited string to the specified loop variable `I` and would execute the command line with **CD** and **GOTO**.

A directory name could be for example  `;Test Folder`, i.e. a directory name starting with a space and a semicolon and containing one more space. Such a directory name would be split up to `;Test` (without space at beginning) and `Folder` and next ignored by **FOR** because of `;Test` starts with a semicolon.

For that reason the end of line character is redefined from default semicolon to a vertical bar with `eol=|` which is a character no file or folder name can contain according to Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). And line splitting behavior is disabled with `delims=` at end of options argument string after `for /F` which defines an empty list of delimiters. So the directory name as output by **DIR** is assigned to loop variable `I` without any modification even on being a very unusual name for a directory.

**FOR** executes command **CD** which changes current directory to the last modified subdirectory of the current directory and next command **GOTO** is executed to continue the processing of the batch file on the line below the label line `:DoneCD`. So the **FOR** loop execution is broken already after processing first directory name with command **GOTO**.

It is of course possible to use other commands after the **FOR** command line and the label line `:DoneCD` than just the **ECHO** line reporting that no subdirectory was found in current directory as shown by referencing dynamic environment variable `CD` like a command line to exit batch processing on this unusual use case or error condition case.

This **FOR** command line with the command **GOTO** to exit **FOR** loop after **CD** cannot be used in a Windows command prompt window. A solution for Windows command prompt window would be:

```
set "DoneCD=" & (@for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir * /AD /B /O-D 2^>nul') do @if not defined DoneCD cd "%I" & set "DoneCD=1") & set "DoneCD="
```

In a batch file this [single line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) would be written as

```
@set "DoneCD=" & (@for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir * /AD /B /O-D 2^>nul') do @if not defined DoneCD cd "%%I" & set "DoneCD=1") & set "DoneCD="
```

or better readable in its multi-line version with an additional `echo` as

```
@echo off
set "DoneCD="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir * /AD /B /O-D 2^>nul') do (
    if not defined DoneCD (
        cd "%%I"
        set "DoneCD=1"
    )
)
if not defined DoneCD echo No subdirectory found in: "%CD%"
set "DoneCD="
```

First the environment variable `DoneCD` is deleted if it is defined by chance.

Next **FOR** runs `cmd.exe` with **DIR** as described above and processes the first output directory with newest modification date. The **IF** condition is true on newest directory as the environment variable was definitely undefined before execution of **FOR**. So command **CD** is executed to change the current directory to newest subdirectory. Then the environment variable `DoneCD` is defined with value `1`. Any other value would be also possible like on using `set "DoneCD=%%I"`. Important here is that for the other subdirectories output by **DIR** the environment variable `DoneCD` is now defined and so the **IF** condition is always false. So there is no attempt made to change in current subdirectory of initial current directory into a subdirectory not existing here or existing by chance also in the subdirectory.

Finally the environment variable `DoneCD` is deleted again if defined at all during execution of **FOR**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?` ... explaining on last help page dynamic environment variable `CD`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. It would have taken me ages to figure this out myself. I'll come back to this post every time I have a question about anything related to `cmd` :)

Comment: How does one go about debugging this? I went into a dir, ran the script there and it worked fine, then went somewhere else, but running it again makes it try to cd into the original directory, which gives me a 'cannot find path specified' error. This persists even after cmd closes. It seems like the current directory is ignored and the original "current directory" persists. FIX: Change `*` to `%cd%` after `dir`.

Comment: @Unknow0059 The usage of `dir * /AD /B /O-D` or just `dir /AD /B /O-D` or `dir "%CD%" /AD /B /O-D` or `dir .\* /AD /B /O-D` should not make ever a difference as in all four cases the command __DIR__ searches in __current directory__ for subdirectories and outputs them ordered by last modification date with latest (newest) subdirectory output first. The usage of `%cd%` after command `dir` instead of `*` is not correct on current directory path containing a space one or of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` as in this case the path must be enclosed in `"`.

Comment: @Unknow0059 Please note that __current directory__ and *batch file directory* is not the same, except the batch file is stored on a local or network drive with a drive letter assigned and the batch file is started with a double click. In this case Windows shell starts `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file with setting first the batch file directory as current directory for Windows command processor. The asterisk after `dir` can be replaced by `"%~dp0"` or `"%~dp0*"` to search for subdirectories in directory of the batch file independent on what is the current directory at the moment.